# AsyncItemWriter - Facing ClassCastException when unwrapping custom class into Future

Tags: java, spring-batch

I'm writing a spring batch job that reads some data and writes it to a file. The data is partitioned into 3 chunks, each of which need to be written to an individual file before being combined. The reading and aggregation are working fine.

However, when the asynchronous writer is throwing an error -- **java.lang.ClassCastException: class package.Custom cannot be cast to class java.util.concurrent.Future**

It seems like my Custom DTO isn't unwrapping into a Future object.
Here's my abridged code

```
 @Bean
    public Step workerStep() throws Exception {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get(WORKER_BEAN)
                .<Custom, Custom>chunk(CHUNK_SIZE)
                .reader(reader(null))
                .writer(writer())
                .taskExecutor(threadPoolExecutor)
                .throttleLimit(THROTTLE_LIMIT)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public CustomReader reader(@Value("#{stepExecutionContext['currentMod']}") Long currentMod) {
        if ( ... some logic ... ) {
            return null;
        }
        return new CustomReader();
    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public AsyncItemWriter writer() throws Exception {
        AsyncItemWriter<Custom> asyncItemWriter = new AsyncItemWriter<>();
        asyncItemWriter.setDelegate(delegateWriter(null));
        asyncItemWriter.afterPropertiesSet();
        return asyncItemWriter;
    }

    @Bean(destroyMethod=EMPTY)
    @StepScope
    public CustomWriter<Custom> delegateWriter(@Value("#{stepExecutionContext['currentMod']}") Long currentMod) {
        CustomWriter<Custom> customWriter = new CustomWriter<>();

        customWriter.setLineAggregator(new DelimitedLineAggregator<Custom>() {
            {
                setDelimiter(COMMA);
                setFieldExtractor(new BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<Custom>() {
                    {
                        setNames( ... get names logic ... );
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        customWriter.setResource(new FileSystemResource(name));
        
        // ... header call-back logic ...
        
        customWriter.setAppendAllowed(true);
        customWriter.setShouldDeleteIfEmpty(true);
        customWriter.setShouldDeleteIfExists(true);
        return customWriter;
    }

    @Bean
    public TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
        return new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor(THREAD_NAME_PREFIX);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `AsyncItemWriter` expects items that are wrapped in a `Future` (See [Javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.2.x/api/org/springframework/batch/integration/async/AsyncItemWriter.html#write-java.util.List-)), and this is typically done by an `AsyncItemProcessor`. The `AsyncItemWriter` and `AsyncItemProcessor` are used in conjunction to implement a fork/join scenario, see [Asynchronous Processors](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.2.x/reference/html/spring-batch-integration.html#asynchronous-processors) section.

Comment: Thank you this helped!